# Join from 3 tables with condition

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables like `table1`, `table2` and `table3` and

**table1**

```
t1_id, t1_name, t1_bookid
```

**table2**

```
t2_id, t2_name, t2_t1_id, t2_bookid
```

**table3**

```
t3_id, t3_name, t3_detail
```

I want fetch `t3_id` if `t2_bookid==t3_id` else `t1_bookid==t3_id`

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
Select t3.id
From table3 t3
Where exists (Select 1
           From table1 t1 where t1.bookId=t3.id)
   Or exists  (Select 1
          From table2 t2 where t2.bookId=t3.id)
```